# Delete item from data in reactjs and redux

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-redux, react-hooks, omdbapi

I am practicing react redux together with oMdb api. I have a method to search movies from the api and add them to a favorites list.
The problem comes when I want to remove a movie from the favorites list.

**Here I show you the code of the reducer**

```
const initialState = {
    favoriteMovies: [],
}


const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_MOVIE":
            return {
                ...state,
                favoriteMovies: [...state.favoriteMovies, action.payload]
            }
        case "DELETE_MOVIE":
            return {
                // ...state, favoriteMovies: [...state.favoriteMovies.slice(action.payload,+1),...state.favoriteMovies.slice(0, action.payload)], 
                ...state, favoriteMovies: [...state.favoriteMovies.filter((favoriteMovie)=>favoriteMovie !==action.payload), console.log("state.favoriteMovies", state.favoriteMovies)]

            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

(The add method works perfectly, but none the two methods that I have tried to remove from the favorites list has worked. **The slice method** returns only the item that I want to remove, **while the filter** method tells me that favorites is undefined.)

**Here I show you the Sandbox where I do the action**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import SearchSection from "./SearchSection";
import Carousel from "../components/carousels/Carousel";
import CarouselItem from "../components/carousels/CarouselItem";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import "../assets/styles/Global.css"
import { deleteMovie } from "../store/actions";

const Sandbox = () => {
    const favoriteMovies = useSelector(state => state.favoriteMovies)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    return (
        <div className="sandbox">
            <SearchSection />
            <Carousel>
                {
                    favoriteMovies.map(favorites =>
                        <CarouselItem
                            title={favorites.Title}
                            image={favorites.Poster}
                            alt={favorites.title}
                            year={favorites.Year}
                            click={() => { dispatch(deleteMovie(favorites)) }}
                        />
                    )}
            </Carousel>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Sandbox;
```

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: How did you implement for add moive ?? because here there are a few mistakes in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter on `id` for example instead of the full object.
When you compare objects, it will be compared by shallow reference and they will be different.

```js
favoriteMovies: state.favoriteMovies.filter((favoriteMovie) => favoriteMovie.id !== action.payload.id)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting like below, you don't have to use ... and de-sturcture the array

favoriteMovies: state.favoriteMovies.filter((favoriteMovie)=>favoriteMovie !==action.payload)

Answer (score 0):

you could also take the approach

```
const newMovies = [...state.movies]

const indexOfMovie = state.movies.findIndex(movie => movie.id === action.payload.id)

if(indexOfMovie !== -1) {
newMovies.splice(indexOfMovie, 1)
} else {
return {...state}
}

set the state of the new movies

return {
..state, 
favoriteMovies: newMovies
}
```